# TaskStackBuilder not returning to MainActivity

Tags: java, android, xml

So i was working out on Android notifications,

I tried out one the examples of notification on [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html):

In one of the examples it shows, how to open an activity from notification.

So the Problem is that:  When i try to press back button on the activity opened by notification it should go back to MainActivity but the app closes out.

ResultActivity is just the default empty Activity with a TextView

MainActivity.java:

```
// The id of the channel.

String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_more)
                .setContentTitle("Event tracker")
                .setContentText("Events received");

NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle =
        new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

String[] events = new String[6];

// / Sets a title for the Inbox in expanded layout
inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle("Event tracker details:");

// Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);

TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

// Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);

// Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);

PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

// Moves events into the expanded layout
for (int i=0; i < events.length; i++) {
    events[i] = "Event " + i;
    inboxStyle.addLine(events[i]);
}

// Moves the expanded layout object into the notification object.
mBuilder.setStyle(inboxStyle);

mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="justjava.andriod.example.com.notificationchannel">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ResultActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the line:

```
stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
```

With:

```
stackBuilder.addParentStack(ResultActivity.class);
```

Also add the `<meta-data` tag to your activity in the manifest if you're testing on API level less than 16

```
<meta-data
    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
    android:value=".MainActivity"/>
```